# ASP.NET MVC - 401 Error when connecting to web service from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, cross-domain

I am trying to make a cross-domain call to a "web service" (I say that because it is simply a site that returns XML based upon a query string value) but having no luck. Each time I make the request I receive a `(401) Unauthorized` error. I can put the link in my browser, however, and alter the query string to get the results, so I should have access to the site from my computer. Below is the code I am trying to use, can anyone offer any suggestions?

The call to the web service originates with an Ajax call on from the page's view. That code is pasted below:

```
function GetProgramDetails() {
    var searchItem = $('.searchbox').val();
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("compSearch", "Home")',
        data:
            {
                searchFilter: searchItem,
                url: location.protocol + '//' + location.host 
            },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert("Unable to process your resquest at this time.");
        }
    });
}
```

This makes a call to the view's controller below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string compSearch(string searchFilter, string url)
    {
        string results = string.Empty;
        string URL =
            "http://quahildy01/xRMDRMA02/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet?$select=AccountId,Name,neu_UniqueId&$filter=startswith(Name,'" +
            searchFilter + "')";

        try
        {
            WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL);
            myWebRequest.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", url);

            WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream myFileStreamResult = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
            Encoding encoder = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(myFileStreamResult, encoder);

            results = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            results = ex.InnerException.ToString();
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: :- Just curious , your not using any [Authorize] keyword right?